# Image in fixed div - Interesting Firefox behavior

Tags: css, image, firefox, html

Consider the following example: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/10/))

HTML:

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell blue"></div><div class="cell"><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/25sa9z4.png" /></div><div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue.cell {
  background-color: blue;
}
.row {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.board {
  width: 48px;
}
```

In Chrome 17 and Safari 5.1.4, the blue cell is in the first row, as expected.
But, in Firefox 11.0 the blue cell is in the second row!

Why is this difference? How to make this consistent?

Comment: looks like a issue of browser compatibility

Comment: Dar see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: then where your blue box should be? please let me know. as i have seen the fiddle in chrome and on the basis of that i update the fiddle. What is you requirement.

Comment: see my updated fiddle and this time i am not assuming the blue box should be in top left;

Comment: See the css also and this time answer is as per your expectation and generic.

Comment: Dear see the little bit explanation, this time i have explain the issue and difference of rendering behavior in diff browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fiddle and demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/12/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/12/embedded/result/

updated Fiddle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/23/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/23/embedded/result/

```
.cell {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.blue.cell {
    background-color: blue;
}
.row {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
.board {
    width: 48px;
}
```

See below image:

[image]

The berries image is taking the height more than cells height so FF is showing rendring issue. This is browser compatibility issue and chrome and safari are webkit based browser so they both render similarly. In FF by default the elements are not Vertical-align:top; so we have to set the css properties to make the elements for browser compatibility.

Comment: It doesn't explain why Firefox renders this differently. Also, you assumed that the blue cell should be at the left top corner, which is not true.

Comment: then where your blue box should be? please let me know.

Comment: It can be anywhere in the first row. The solution must be generic.

Comment: For expected behavior in every browser see my updated fiddle. An it is generic solution.

Comment: It's an interesting workaround, but an explanation for this browsers difference is still missing in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the second cell that is blue, it is the first cell that is blue. The difference is positioning.

In Safari & Chrome, the cells are aligned at the top because WebKit knosw two elements cannot occupy the same space and restyles a few other elements to get the right output *which is why WebKit is the best*. In Firefox, the cells are pushed to the bottom, because the image is aligned at the baseline. So it appears the second cell is blue, but really the first cell is.

Try setting the `vertical-align` to `top` on the `img` and you'll see the cells with be aligned to the top and the first cell is blue. http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/21/

Comment: Uh...  Two elements can absolutely occupy "the same space" in CSS.  And yes, the image and the inline-block are on the same line, and both baseline-aligned by default, so their baselines should be lined up.  WebKit is just getting this layout completely wrong, unless it has UA styles setting non-default alignment on img elements.